# Oracle bind all $_POST's

Tags: php, oracle, post

I am using `oci_bind_by_name()`.

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":post1", $_POST['post1']);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":post2", $_POST['post2']);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":post3", $_POST['post3']);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":post4", $_POST['post4']);
...
```

Is it possible to do this dynamically in PHP, for all `$_POST` keys call `oci_bind_by_name()` of the same name?

Just to simplify my code, as I have 50 or so calls to `oci_bind_by_name()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be simply done with a `foreach` loop over the `$_POST` array, using the key as the parameter name:

```
// Bind all in a loop:
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":$key", $value);
}
```

However, you cannot guarantee that the client has sent you the keys in POST that you actually want. It is important then to check them against an array of keys that are actually valid for use in the prepared statement:

```
$valid_keys = array(
  'post1',
  'post2',
  ...
  ...
  'post99'
);
```

Then loop over those instead, checking that they were actually sent in the POST before attempting to use them.

```
foreach ($valid_keys as $key) {
  if (!isset($_POST[$key])) {
     // ERROR! Needed key was not present in $_POST!
     // Break the loop if you can't execute the statement...
  }
  else {
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":$key", $_POST[$key]);  
  }
}
```

If you are intending to build the prepared statement's SQL string dynamically, it is especially important to maintain a list of safe  parameter names.

Answer (score 1):

If you do use a simple foreach loop to bind each variable; do NOT bind to a loop variable $value

```
 // Bind all in a loop: but DO NOT use $value
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":$key", $_POST[$key]);
 }
```

To quote from the manual [Example 3 of oci_bind_by_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php):

```
foreach ($ba as $key => $val) { 
   // oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $val) does not work
   // because it binds each placeholder to the same location: $val
   // instead use the actual location of the data: $ba[$key]
   oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $ba[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Except for changing `$value` to `$_POST[$key]` this is essentially copied from the other answer. Also I think you should explain why one shouldn't use `$value`? I think it doesn't makes _any_ difference.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to help with dates